# jQuery If text in div1 matches text any part of div2, add a class to div1

Tags: jquery, arrays, filter, indexing, hover

Since I've been experimenting with jQuery for just a few days now, a few things (like arrays) are still breaking my brain. Unraveling a indexOf function, for example, feels like trying to turn right while backing out a driveway, in England. Regardless, I took a stab at applying a class based on a comparison of one div to the index of another...and (of course) I can't get it to work. Hopefully, you can tell me if I'm "warm" with the following script. Or, if not, how to fix it.

In short: The basic idea is that if you hover over any .elbox div, the script compares the text in the .skemps div of that elbox to the content in each .pjemp div; and, if it finds a match, applies a class to the matching .pjemp div.

**Div1: #ptosEmps li div**

```
<div id="ptosEmps"> 
 <div class="menu">
  <ul id="menu"> 
    <li><div class="pjemp"><a>T</a></div></li>
    <li><div class="pjdesc">T Description</div></li>
    <li><div class="pjemp"><a>I</a></div></li>
    <li><div class="pjdesc">I Description</div></li>
    <!-- ... (one primary li and description li for each of the .skemps letters -->
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Div2: #ptosTable .elbox .skemps**

```
<div id="ptosTable">
 <div class="elbox">
  content
  <div class="skemps">T,I,H,P,W,L,N,F</div>
 </div>
 <!-- About 100 of these. .skemps div can contain one or more of those letters. -->
</div>
```

**Script (doesn't work):**

```
$('#ptosEmps li').filter(":even").hover(function() {
    $(this).filter(function() {
    return $('#ptosTable .skemps').text().indexOf($('.pjemp').text()) == -1;
        //if skemps = any text in menu div, return true?
    }).addClass('.emp_hi');
},
function() {
    $(this).removeClass('.emp_hi');
});
```

I think maybe I need to somehow define the entire filter function as a $(this), then say something like "$(this).addclass('.emp_hi');" But how?

### ----------

For the record, I forgot to mention that the text in Div2 (which triggers addClass in Div1) was also hidden via css. So, working from BumbleB2na's suggestion, this is what I ended up with (**WORKS!**):

```
$('.elbox').hover(function() {
    var arrSkemp = $(this).children('.skemps').text().split(',');
    $.each(arrSkemp, function(index, value) {
        $('.pjemp:contains(' + value + ')').addClass('emp_hi');
    });
},
function() {

    $('.pjemp').removeClass('emp_hi');
});
```

Props to BumbleB2na---both for helping me to work out the kinks in my question and for a speedy, very functional response that did not break my brain!

Comment: by .pjemp do you mean .pjdesc?  You want to see if 'I' from skemps text: 'T,I,H,P,W,L,N,F' matches 'I' in pjdesc text:  'I Description' ?

Comment: oh dude, you are missing the 'pjemp' class on the div before each 'pjdesc' div

Comment: `$('#.pjemp')` is wrong `#` is used to `getElementById` and `.` is the get the element(s) by class

Comment: can you double-check your question for me? i'm confused cause the javascript doesn't match up with your html elements.

Comment: Good eye, Bumble! Added the pjemp class to question samples...and the ptosTable div. (Simplifing my markup for the examples kinda backfired.)

Comment: Thanks, 3nigma. Corrected in script sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K [try my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BumbleB2na/h42Rw/) out and maybe it will help. I couldn't get indexOf() to work but here's the code I would go with:

```
$('.skemps').hover(function() {
    var arrSkemp = $(this).text().split(',');
    $.each(arrSkemp, function(index, value) { 
        $('.pjemp:contains(' + value + ')').addClass('emp_hi');
    });
},
function() {
    var arrSkemp = $(this).text().split(',');
        $.each(arrSkemp, function(index, value) { 
            $('.pjemp:contains(' + value + ')').removeClass('emp_hi');
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, I /think/ that helps. Let me just figure out how to plug it into my local thing, and I'll accept. Thank you!

Comment: Ah, so there's a variable in my local version that's confungling things (.skemps is hidden). But the short of it is that your approach works for the sample given and still helps a lot. Thanks, BumbleB2na!

Comment: Okay. I haven't used IndexOf() a whole lot, but I'm sure that there could be a faster solution. One way to speed this up is to use selectors like you were using ('#ptostable .skemps') b/c then jQuery does not have to traverse the entire DOM.